# emit event from another event node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to get new connected user list in **admin.html**

1. client.html (client login authentication)
2. admin.html (notify new user join)

**server.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('client.html');
});
app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('admin.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('login', function(msg){
    socket.emit('notification', 'new user joined');
  });

  socket.on('notification', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

Here I can try emit **notification** event from **login** event but it did not print anything in console, **login** event get trigger from **client.html**.

When I try this from **client.html**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    var a= $('#username').val();
    var b= $('#usermail').val();
    var c= $('#reason').val()
    socket.emit('login',{username:a,usermail:b,reason:c});
    socket.emit('notification','new user joined');

  });

</script>
```

login event only get emit, **notification** does not work, when I run with notification event alone while it is working.

**note:** Suppose if I do from **admin.html**, I need set time looping for continuously check whether the new user have added or not. That is why I am looking automatically trigger the event while user connected.

please advice me how to achieve this?

Comment: `socket.emit('notification', 'new user joined');` emits `notification` event on client, not on the server.

Comment: is it any way to emit event from server side? or suggest how to show new user in admin.phtml

Comment: Yes, write same line on client. Check out http://socket.io/docs/ for more details

Comment: now only caught what you told @MukeshSharma :-) I have tried with client.html also but no luck please review my updated question

Comment: share logic of `client.phtml`

Comment: I have updated please review @MukeshSharma

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
io.sockets.emit('notification', '')
```

This will emit everyone. I guess you can catch that event in admin.html.

But if you think the data needs to be secure and you don't want to send everyone, you can use socket io `rooms`.

In admin.html

```
//after socket connection
socket.emit('join_admin_room')
```

in your socket codes:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 

    socket.on('join_admin_room', function(){ //from admin.html
       socket.join('admin'); //add this socket to admin room
    })

    socket.on('login', function(msg){ /from index.html
       //this will go to sockets in admin room
       io.to('admin').emit('notification') //to admin.html
     });

});
```

More information: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: great Idea dude. It worked. +1 from me but it seems not a proper way because it is brodcast to every client (all the details are confidential, I need to restrict will send admin only ). However I am not sure, If you felt this is the right way, please update your answer with your strong reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('login', function(msg){
    socket.broadcast.emit('notification', 'new user joined');
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

The code of `socket.on('notification', ...)` on server doesn't work because it is server that has emitted `notification`